# Choose the correct product notation or summation for the expression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I need to choose weather this is a product notation or a summation. I can figure out which one it is.

I have this expression:

$$2 \times 4 \times 6 \times 8 \times 10 \ldots \times 40$$

The answer is either:

> $$\sum_{m=2}^{40} m$$

**or**

> $$\prod_{m=2}^{40} m$$

Comment: Mathjaxed for future reference.  Neither is correct though.

Comment: FYI, "product" is just a fancy name for "result of multiplying stuff together".

Comment: I'm genuinely curious. They taught you about the product notation, but they didn't teach you that "product" means "multiplication"? Or they didn't teach you that $\times$ is multiplication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither of your proposal is correct.

For your first guess, it means $$2+3+4+\ldots+ 40$$

For your second guess, it means $$2(3)(4) \ldots (40)$$

You are multiplying even numbers, it should be

$$\prod_{i=1}^{20} (2i)$$

Answer (score 4):

You are multiplying values, so you should probably use the product notation:

$$\prod_{m=1}^{20}2m = 2 \times 4 \times 6 ... \times 40$$

When you have something like $\prod_{m=2}^{40}m$ as in your example, this actually represents the product $2 \times 3 \times 4 ... \times 39 \times 40$ - it includes the odd numbers too, since $m$ increases by $1$ each time. To increase it by $2$, use $(2m)$ in the product instead of just $m$.

Answer (score 4):

Can also be expressed as 
$$2^{20} 20!$$

Comment: :D most helpful

Comment: @Marcel - Thank you :)

Comment: An alternative notation is sometimes used: the [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) $40!!$, where $n!!$ means the product of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$ and of the same parity as $n$, that is, $2\times4\times6\times\cdots\times n$ if $n$ is even and $1\times3\times5\times\cdots\times n$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Yes that's right. I wonder if a triple factorial exists, e.g. $9!!!=9\times 6\times 3$...

Comment: @hypergeometric : [Yes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html).  See also [multifactorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials), where a slightly less awful notation is shown.

Comment: @EricTowers - Thanks. How interesting$!^{(k)}$

Answer (score 3):

Neither is correct. It is in fact the product notation, as summation notation would be $2+4+6+8+...+40$, however, the expression is incorrect. The correct expression is $\prod_{m=1}^{20}2m$. There is a way to do it with summation notation, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.